# Where to find the DTD of Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, configuration

The DTD in the hibernate jar is a good way to know what are the attributes that can be included and the expected name for that tag.

Opening up the DTD file is the easiest way to get an overview of all elements and attributes, and to view the defaults, as well as some comments.

This will help the programmer to write hibernate.cfg.xml file from scracth(crazy but some people do ask this to achieve without using internet :O )

Please tell where to locate the DTD when we have a hibernate jar.

This is not a programming question but will be helpful for programmer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Hibernate 5 and newer

DTD:

```
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

XSD:

```
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-3.0.xsd
hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-3.0.xsd
```

### Hibernate 4

```
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd 
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

and Hibernate 4 was upgraded to use XSDs as well:

```
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-4.0.xsd
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-4.0.xsd
```

### Hibernate 3

For old versions, like [hibernate3.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/h/Downloadhibernate3jar.htm) you can find them under:

```
hibernate3.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
hibernate3.jar\org\hibernate\hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

For any version 3.x or above not listed here, you can find these files in your `hibernate-core-X.x.Final.jar` archive under the `org.hibernate` package

Comment: The packaging structure for hibernate-core jar and hibernate3.jar is different. Can you please add that too. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an image by which you will get a clear image in your mind that’s where will you get DTD.
[Click me to open Image for hibernate DTD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqxBO.png)

Open jar file respectively.

```
hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar
org.hibernate
hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd
```

**When you will open org.hibernate**

You will get two dtd

one for

```
Hibernate configuration
Hibernate mapping
```

Hibernate configuration

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Hibernate Mapping

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```