# Why do we write <!DOCTYPE> tag in Hibernate Configuration or Mapping file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, xsd, dtd

To validate the xml we need either dtd or xsd. If we want to validate the xml against the dtd then we need to write this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

Where SYSTEM is used when our dtd is present in file system and PUBLIC is used if our dtd is present in somewhere network. In this case if we are writing this one

```
"http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"
```

Means our dtd is present in network with this address and our hibernate-configuration xml file will be validated against this dtd.

But Why do write this one ???????

```
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
```

So please answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN` in the DOCTYPE is the [Formal Public Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_Public_Identifier). It uniquely identifies the `PUBLIC` [external entity](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-ExternalID), and may be used to resolve a URI reference.

> In addition to a system identifier, an external identifier may include a *public identifier*.
>
> An XML processor attempting to retrieve the entity's content may use any combination of the public and system identifiers as well as additional information outside the scope of this specification to try to generate an alternative URI reference. If the processor is unable to do so, it must use the URI reference specified in the system literal. Before a match is attempted, all strings of white space in the public identifier must be normalized to single space characters (#x20), and leading and trailing white space must be removed.

Also, a good reference explaining the components of the FPI: https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/dtd_fpi.cfm

> Here's a real life example of an FPI. In this case, the DTD was created by the W3C for XHTML:
>
> `-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN`
>
> An FPI is made up of 4 fields, each separated by double forward slashes (`//`):
>
> 1. `-` Indicates whether the DTD is connected to a formal standard or not. If the DTD hasn't been approved (for example, you've defined the DTD yourself), use a hypen (-). If the DTD has been approved by a nonstandards body, use a plus sign "+". If the DTD has been approved by a formal standards body this field should be a reference to the standard itself.
> 2. `W3C`  Holds the name of the group (or person) responsible for the DTD. The above example is maintained by the W3C, so "W3C" appears in the second field.
> 3. `DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional`   Indicates the type of document that is being described. This usually contains some form of unique identifier (such as a version number).
> 4. `EN`   Specifies the language that the DTD uses. This is achieved by using the two letter identifier for the language (i.e. for english, use "EN").

Comment: I understood the above explanation but i have another doubt. To validate the XML we need DTD but our hibernate-configuration dtd file is  present in "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" this location. To go this location we require internet connection. But without internet connection how it is working ??

Comment: With a custom Entity Resolver https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/xml/sax/EntityResolver.html, you could load a local DTD resource, instead of depending upon resolving from the internet.

Comment: The hibernate distribution includes the DTD in the jar, allowing it to be resolved from the classpath: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24407435/14419

Comment: Yes, Hibernate distribution includes the DTD in the jar itself and internally it loads the DTD file from classpath by taking the help of ClassLoader. And by using `org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver` class it gets the real file name as `hibernate-configuration-4.0`. 
 DTDEntityResolver class has a method called `public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId)` which returns the real file name as `hibernate-configuration-4.0`. **But my question is who calls the resolveEntity() method of class DTDEntityResolver in Hibernate?**_Does Configuration class calls ??_

Comment: Hibernate registers it’s custom entity resolver https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/reference/en/html/mapping.html

Answer (score 0):

**A Doctype describes which DTD/XSD the XML file follows.**

It indicates what elements are allowed inside what other elements (for the purpose of validation).

It also decides what named character references are available (beyond the 5 XML built-ins of `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`)